# How do I write SQL query for filtering out two columns with the same value?

Tags: sql

I have 1 table with two columns for Fname and Lname.
I want to find all the value of Fname that has the same value as Lname.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE Fname = Lname` ... is that really your question?  What database are you using?  Can you show us a query or data?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm just getting my feet wet with SQL and I saw in a different post someone was using Fname LIKE % = Lname LIKE %;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Somphone Kounkong ... try this,

```
`select Fname from sampleTable where Fname=Lname`
```